# Navigation Drawer is very wide

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have implemented Navigation drawer similar to [Android Sliding Menu using Navigation Drawer](http://goo.gl/0xCKz7). The slide menu is coming up properly, but very wide (The width is very long).. When I check it in my Phone/TAB it is very long both portrait and landscape mode. It is almost touching the other side of the screen. Something like a full screen.

When I run the project given in AndroidHive. Things are fine. I have just tuned the XML to by requirements that is all

Here is the drawer list XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/maps" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundcircle"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is ListView.XML which has the Slide ListView

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong?

Comment: Show us the layout which contains the `DrawerLayout` I am pretty much 100% sure that the width specified there is too big.

Comment: The best way to that is to actually set the NavigationView width to "wrap_content":     <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified a proper width for your `NavigationDrawer`. If you set the width to `match_parent` it will - as the name implies - be as big as the parent. And you don't want the `NavigationDrawer` to be as big as the screen, so specify a width of about `240dp`. Try something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Let me try this out.. the reason for me to change 240dp is because what if the screen resolution is bigger it would end up showing the menu very small.

Comment: No it doesn't, dp (or dip) are density independent pixel. 240dp is the same physical size on all screens.

Answer (score 2):

The `ListView` needs to have a smaller width. Try `android:layout_width="240dp"`.

This is basically based on the official guide: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

My tip: Double check tutorials with official documentation :)

Comment: 240dp did the job.. My bad. I should have seen the docs. I have been working on it for couple hours now.. Trying out different ways!